# Using 2 cursors, one to get a parameter for the other

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am doing an exercies that requires me to use 2 explicit cursors.  One cursor is to get a parameter for the second.  The end goal is to find the most recent 'rental date' for each car based on registration.  For example, registration 345JKL was rented on the 01/06/2010, 07/09/2011 and 08/09/2013.  I want this to only return the most recent date which is 08/09/2013 and I want it to provide a most recent date for every registration in the table.

I am aware that there are better ways to do this such as MAX, subqueries etc (both of which I am not allowed to use), but as a 'lateral thinking exercise' I am required to do it without inbuilt functions, subqueries and the rest of the things that make life easy.

I am a little stuck with this one.

This is what I have so far which is getting me nowhere:

```
    declare
v_maxdate DATE;
v_reg VARCHAR2(20);

cursor reg_cur IS 
SELECT * FROM i_car;
v_car reg_cur%ROWTYPE;

cursor c_reg (reg i_booking.registration%TYPE) IS
SELECT date_reserved from i_booking
WHERE registration = reg;
v_date c_reg%ROWTYPE;

begin
FOR v_date IN c_reg (v_car.registration) LOOP
v_maxdate := '01/JAN/90';
If v_date > v_maxdate THEN
v_maxdate := v_date;
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

It is throwing me this error:

```
If v_date > v_maxdate THEN
          *
ERROR at line 17: 
ORA-06550: line 17, column 11: 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '>' 
ORA-06550: line 17, column 1: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I figured rather than continuing to bang my head on the desk I would ask for guidance.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You do not need a cursor. You can just happily join the two tables.

Comment: As I said, part of the exercise is to do it this way, which is a bugger but it is what it is.

Comment: Yeah cursors are like smoking if you have not started dont. Most of the companies I have worked for using a cursor normally resulted in getting into serious hot water. Go look at RBAR and understand why we dont use cursors in the real world.

Comment: v_date is like a record for the cursor using which u can access all the columns of the cursor use IF v_date.date_reserved > v_maxdate THEN v_maxdate := v_date.date_reserved;

Answer (score 0):

The `v_date` variable is a record, so you have to use the dot to actually access some of its fields - `date_reserved` in your case:

```
begin
  v_maxdate := '01/JAN/90';
  FOR v_date IN c_reg (v_car.registration) LOOP
    If v_date.date_reserved > v_maxdate THEN
      v_maxdate := v_date;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

I have also moved initialization of `v_maxdate` outside of the loop.